# @volatile usage unclear - sending an object with a `var` to another thread

Tags: scala, concurrency

I am not sure I use `@volatile` correctly here. I have a buffer, like this:

```
final class BufD(val buf: Array[Double], @volatile var size: Int)
```

Which is sent between processes, whereby it might cross thread boundaries. The sender may update the `size` field just before sending it out. Therefore I want to make sure that the receiver under no circumstances can see a stale `size` value here. **First question:** Does `@volatile` ensure this or is it redundant?

Now I am introducing a trait:

```
trait BufLike {
  @volatile var size: Int
}

final class BufD(val buf: Array[Double], @volatile var size: Int) extends BufLike
```

This gives me a compiler warning:

> Warning:(6, 4) no valid targets for annotation on method size - it is discarded unused. You may specify targets with meta-annotations, e.g. @(volatile @getter)
>
> ```
>  @volatile var size: Int
>   ^
> ```

**Second question:** Should I remove the `@volatile` here or change it in a different way?

Comment: why don't you just use immutable case class + `.copy()`?

Comment: Example: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-case-class-copy-method-example

Comment: @tair Because this is high speed DSP code and I prefer to avoid any unnecessary allocations as far as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume thread-A creates, updates, then passes the object-X to thread-B. If object-X and whatever it refers to directly or transitively (fields) are no further updated by thread-A, then `volatile` is redundant. The consistency of the object-X state at the receiving thread is guaranteed by JVM.

In other words, if *logical ownership* for object-X is passed from thread-A to thread-B, then `volatile` doesn't make sense. Conversely, on modern multicore systems, the performance implications of `volatile` can be more than that of thread-local garbage left by immutable case classes.

If object-X is supposed to be shared for writing, making a field `volatile` will help to share its value, but you will face another problem: non-atomic updates on the object-X, if fields' values depend on each other.

As @alf pointed out, to benefit from *happens-before* guarantees, the objects must be passed safely! This can be achieved using `java.util.concurrent.**` classes. High level constructs like Akka define their own mechanisms of "passing" objects safely.

References:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Comment: Strictly saying, _`volatile` is redundant_ and _The consistency ... is guaranteed by JVM._ only in case when the object was passed between threads safely, i.e. the moment when thread A "passes" the object, whatever it may mean, _happens-before_ (by JVM definition) the moment thread B starts reading it. In most cases you can rely on an existing synchronization, e.g. a blocking queue or an atomic reference. Without an existing mechanism, you need to build your own, and `volatile` can be such a mechanism (although I would not recommend it).

Comment: @alf thanks for the additional comment. I have received note now from the Akka authors (the framework that is used to pass objects around) that indeed the happens-before guarantee applies here.

Comment: In case of akka BTW you should not really assume you're on the same JVM, which makes another argument in favor of immutable objects.

Answer (score 3):

As @tair points out, the real solution to your problem is to use an immutable case class:

> The sender may update the size field just before sending it out.

It seems that receiver does *not* update the size; neither does sender update the size after if has already sent the `BufD` out. So for all practical reasons, recipient is much better off receiving an immutable object.

As for `@volatile`, it ensures visibility—the writes are indeed hitting the main memory instead of being cached in the thread local cache, and the reads include a memory barrier to ensure that the value read is not stale.

Without `@volatile`, the recipient thread is free to cache the value (it's not volatile, hence it should not be changed from the other thread, hence it's safe to cache) and re-use it instead of referring to the main memory. ([SLS 11.2.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/11-annotations.html#java-platform-annotations), [JLS §8.3.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4))

> `@volatile` Marks a field which can change its value outside the control of the program; this is equivalent to the `volatile` modifier in Java.

and

> A write to a `volatile` field (§8.3.1.4) *happens-before* every subsequent read of that field.

The problem here is that either you don't need all that as the object is effectively immutable (and you're better off with a properly immutable one), or you want to see coordinated changes in `buf` and `size` on the recipient size. In the latter case, `@volatile` may be useful (while fragile), if writer appends (not overwrites!) to `buf`, and then updates the `size`. In this case, write to `buf` [*happens-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) write to `size`, which in turn *happens-before* reader can read the updated value from `size` (by volatility), therefore if reader checks and re-checks the size, and writer only appends, you're probably fine. Having said that, I would not use this design.

As for the warning, it all compiles to Java, i.e. JVM, bytecode, and `volatile` is a JVM flag for *fields*. Traits cannot define a field—they only define methods, and it's up to the extending class to decide whether it'll be a proper variable or (a pair of) methods ([SLS 4.2](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions)).

> A variable declaration `var x: T` is equivalent to the declarations of both a *getter function `x`* and a *setter function `x_=`:*
>
> ```
> def x: T
> def x_= (y: T): Unit
> ```

A function cannot be `@volatile`, hence the warning.